# Anagram pairs in a number list

Tags: algorithm, numbers, anagram

I have a list of numbers. For any given number in the list, I want to find the anagram pair of that given number which is also present in the list.

*E.g. of anagram is 12 is anagram of 21 and 121 is anagram of 112. (assuming all these numbers are present in number list given)*

My initial guess was to do some kind of encoding of each number such that both the anagram number gets the same encoded value and no other number can get that same encoded value. But I cannot find a proper encoding algo.

<s>One encoding algo I thought was to find the sum & product of digits of each number. If there is an anagram present in the list, then it will also have the same sum & product of the digits. But how can I prove that only these anagrams will have this sum & product pair, i.e. no non-anagram number will have same sum & product pair?</s>

**For e.g.** Sum & product pair of 121 & 112 is (4, 2). But could there be any other number with Sum & product pair (4,2)?

Found this **[Sum and Product of n-positive integers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1941758/sum-and-product-of-n-positive-integers)**

Is my assumption correct? Or is there some different algo to find the anagram pair from a number list. I have to find all the anagram pair present in the list.

*E.g. [10, 12, 21, 0, 112, 121] of these (12,21) and (112, 121) are the anagram pairs*

I have seen the word anagram problem, but I believe that since the list comprises of numbers only, there could be faster way, then to check each character of word to another word.

Comment: Hint:  You can sort the digits in each number and use that as an invariant.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff, so after sorting the digits of number, I should create a number from those sorted digits.

Comment: @MasterChief What about calculating the XOR of every digits of the integers in your list?